# Is there a RPM File naming convention in LSB?

Tags: linux, standards, rpm, linux-standard-base

RPM is the package format in LSB but does LSB force any naming standard for RPMs similarly to this:

http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-file-format.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the relevant section of the ["LSB Book"](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/en/Book), [Packaging](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/en/Book/Packaging#Package_Naming), it's  only required

- to prefix your package with `lsb-`
- to register the portion of your package name up to the first hyphen in LANANA (or for it to be your domain name).

However, the standard LSB packaging tool wrapper, `makelsbpkg`, is [said to generate package names in the form](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/en/Book/HowToDevel#makelsbpkg) `mypackage-1.0.0-1.%arch.rpm`, which, I guess is the `name-version-release.architecture.rpm` scheme you linked to.

(I think, it's intended that package name (`mypackange` in the example above, already contains `lsb-` prefix.  I'm not sure, never actually ran the tool.)

Comment: Awsome! That is exactly what I am looking for.