# steps needed to create binary package for distribution in linux

Tags: linux, distribution, fedora, packaging, rpm

I am little confused on how to create a complete binary package using rpmbuild from a project I just created (already compiled binary).

my current project contain similar format as this user ([Packaging proprietary software for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545628/packaging-proprietary-software-for-linux))
Where I have

- foo (binary)
- data
- libs
- foo.sh

*libs* will contain all the shared libraries the project requires, and *foo.sh* is a script that sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include *libs*. Therefore, the user will execute *foo.sh* and the program should start.

I am looking at the tutorial from this site ([rpm tutorial](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch08s02.html))

I understand to create a rpm I create a build area use `rpmdev-setuptree`
I can create a spec file use `cd ~/rpmbuild/SPECS; rpmdev-newspec foo` and if I got a good SOURCES folder I can build it with `rpmbuild -ba foo.spec`

But I have no idea how to setup the SOURCES directory. The tutorial stated ([here](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch08s02s02.html)) that I should create a tarball and place all my source file in it and put in SOURCE directory. What would be the source file in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create a RPM from binary files you have already? In that case, you can just leave the whole building stuff out of the SPEC file, and you need a SOURCE directory to keep the bundles you've got, the `%prep` step described below will take them from here. 
In a binary package I built a while back from zip files, I did:

- Heading, with name, version, description written by me/cribbed from the originals
- Sources: The original places to download the Linux packages, official documentation, ...
- `%prep`: Just unpack the different pieces, delete some redundant files, ...
- `%build`: Nothing to do
- `%install`: Create the relevant directories under `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` by hand, copy files there by `install`, copy/create configuration files, ...
- `%clean`: Blow away `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT`
- `%files`: An exhaustive list of all files installed.

This required a few iterations to get right. Afterwards I followed the upstream package by rebuilding my RPM (conveniently I had everything packaged up in a SRPM, where the Source part was kind of a misnomer...)

Comment: I was going to ask about the .spec next in my questions. Since my project is already binary files. What should I put in %build? as I got no config nor makefile. And what do you mean by "copy files there by `install`, copy/create configuration files,"

Comment: @user1655072, `%build` in my SPEC is just a few comments saying there is nothing to be done.

Comment: sorry meant to ask about %install I meant to get clarification on "copy files there by `install`, copy/create configuration files,"

Comment: @user1655072, use the `install` program to handle installing files, permissions, ...